# Java Web Start object creation

Tags: java, java-web-start

I'm facing a strange problem regarding creating an object from a simple class in java web start. After this line:

```
System.err.println("creating file node");
FileNode nd = new FileNode(tw.getPathString(), tw.getPathString(),
       tw.getObjectId(0), null, ChangeType.ADD);
System.err.println("obj created");
```

All the parameter passed to this constructor returns a value (I checked). The first message is printed but the last is not. The program does not crash but returns to the main menu. The constructor of the FileNode just set the parameters passed as argument, nothing else. Besides that, the FileNode inherit from a superclass (which these parameters are set in) and inside the superclass the printed message is not shown. Here is the FileNode's super class:

```
    public FileNode(String _newName, String _oldName, ObjectId _newObjId, ObjectId _oldObjId, ChangeType _changeType) {
    super(_newName, _oldName, _newObjId, _oldObjId, _changeType);
    System.out.println(_newName);
}
```

And the superclass constructor:

```
public PatchInfo(String _newName, String _oldName, ObjectId _newObjId, ObjectId _oldObjId, ChangeType _changeType){
    System.out.println("adding to " + _newName);
    newName = _newName;
    oldName = _oldName;
    newObjId = _newObjId;
    oldObjId = _oldObjId;
    changeType = _changeType;
}
```

The message ""adding to " + _newName" is not presented.

Does anybody know this problem?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Does `FileNode` class extend `PatchInfo`?

Comment: Yes. That's right.

Comment: If you surround `FileNode nd = new FileNode(...);` with `try { ... } catch (Throwable t) { t.printStackTrace(); }`, what happens?

Comment: I get `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jdt/core/dom/ASTVisitor`